# $f_n:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ seq. of functions, $f_n$ continuous, $f_n$ conv. pointwise but not uniformly to $F$, $F$ be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering if there can be a sequence of functions $f_n: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where

i) Each$f_n$ is continuous on $D$,

ii) $f_n$ converges pointwise on $D$ to some $F$,

iii) $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $F$ and

iv) $F$ is continuous on $D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, consider the maps $f_n : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) = x^n$.  It converges pointwise but not uniformly to the $0$ map, a continuous function.

Comment: Nice thank you very much!